# How to get first occurrence of an item in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with all those infos:

[image]

I exported this data and I am using panda to create a dataframe.
I want to make a new table with only the state and the fips code. Also the fips code is only the 2 first characters without repetition. So will be something like this

```
State      FIPS
CO         08
FL         12
...        ...
```

I thought about using a set, but not sure how to do this.

Comment: This is not hard.  What have you tried?

Comment: df[['Recip_state', 'FIPS']].drop_duplicates()

Answer (score 1):

You can make a copy of your original *Recip_State* and *FIPS* columns to a new dataframe. First [pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) on *Recip_State* column. Then slice the *FIPS* column.

```py
df_ = df[['Recip_State', 'FIPS']].copy()
df_.drop_duplicates(subset=['Recip_State'], inplace=True)
df_['FIPS'] = df_['FIPS'].str[:2]
```

If you want to do it in one line, you can try

```py
df_ = (df[['Recip_State', 'FIPS']].copy()
       .drop_duplicates(subset=['Recip_State'])
       .apply(lambda row: [row['Recip_State'], row['FIPS'][:2]], axis=1, result_type='expand')
       )
```

Comment: I'm just curious how to solve this in one line. Step by step is no problem, but doing it in one line I came to the same result like you: `copy`, `drop_duplicates` (but inplace=False) and then I'm stuck. `df.apply`  with `lambda x: x.str[:2]` on a single column only returns this column as series. `map` only works for series. if applying to the whole `df` I have to go with an if for the right column. Isn't there a better more efficient way?

Comment: @Rabinzel  See my updated answer.